# how does the two-pointer technique eliminate the need to check every element with every element?

Tags: javascript, node.js, algorithm

I was solving a coding problem where:

You are given an integer array height of length n. There are n vertical lines drawn such that the two endpoints of the ith line are (i, 0) and (i, height[i]).

Find two lines that together with the x-axis form a container, such that the container contains the most water.

Return the maximum amount of water a container can store.

https://leetcode.com/problems/container-with-most-water/description/

My answer used brute force but the suggested answer with a time complexity of O(n) was this:

```
var maxArea = function (height) {
  let biggestArea = Number.MIN_VALUE;
  let leftPointer = 0;
  let rightPointer = height.length - 1;

  while (leftPointer < rightPointer) {
    let leftHeight = height[leftPointer];
    let rightHeight = height[rightPointer];
    let heightToUse = leftHeight < rightHeight ? leftHeight : rightHeight;
    let area = heightToUse * (rightPointer - leftPointer);
    biggestArea = Math.max(biggestArea, area);

    if (leftHeight < rightHeight) {
      leftPointer++;
    } else {
      rightPointer--;
    }
  }

  return biggestArea;
};
```

I understand how this solution works but  I still dont understand how the two-pointer technique eliminates the need to check every element with every element.
could someone please explain the logic behind it?
thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how the two-pointer technique eliminates the need to check every element with every element

When you have a pair (`leftPointer`, `rightPointer`), then the least of `height[leftPointer]` and `height[rightPointer]` determines the volume that the corresponding container has.

Let's assume that `height[leftPointer]` is the lesser one (or at least not greater).

Then we know that for any `i` in the range `[leftPointer+1, ..., highPointer]` the volume between `leftPointer` and `i` cannot be *greater* than what we already have. Even if there would be a very high `height[i]` it wouldn't matter as then `height[leftPointer]` is the lesser and determining height. And because the distance between `leftPointer` and `i` is less than the distance between `leftPointer` and `rightPointer`, the volume can never exceed what we already have.

So we don't need to visit those `leftPointer, i` pairs. That's were we avoid making all combinations.

On the other hand, we cannot exclude that there is an `i` where the `i, highPointer` pair would represent a greater volume container. That is why `leftPointer++` is the correct action to take, and then the same reasoning can be applied to the new pair.